# display records in radio button then insert to another table php

Tags: php, insert, record

I need help to get records from a table and view as radio button and insert one of this records depend for what the user choose to another table and i view my records in radio buttons but when i try to select a radio button to insert to another table nothing happened.

```
<form method="post" action="">
<?php
$link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die("Can't Connect...");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER 'utf8'");
mysql_select_db("project",$link) or die("Can't Connect to Database...");
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  mrsh7on  WHERE `major`='$major'");
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
{
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
   {
       echo"<div>";
       echo "<input name=\"radio\" type=\"radio\" required      value=".$row['vip_id'].">
      ".$row['name']."<br />";
       echo"</div>";
  }
  $name = $row['name'];
  $vip_id = $row['vip_id'];
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']) and !empty($_POST['submit']))
{       
if(!empty($_POST['radio']))
{
    $id = $_SESSION['sess_id'];
    $major=$_SESSION['sess_major'];
    $vip_id=$_SESSION['sess_vip_id'];
    $name=$_SESSION['sess_name'];
    $link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die("Can't Connect...");
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER 'utf8'");
    mysql_select_db("project",$link) or die("Can't Connect to Database...");
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  vote WHERE `id`='$id'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
    {
        echo"this user voted before";
    }
    else
    {
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO vote (id, major, vip_id, name)
        VALUES ('$id', '$major', '$vip_id', '$name')");
           mysql_query($sql,$link) or die("mysql_error()");
        echo"Successfully Inserted !";
    }
}
}?>
  <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
```

Comment: change this `<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit">` to this `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">`

Answer (score 1):

**1)** If that is all of your code. Starting off from a million dollar question, Where have you started sessions? Missing `session_start();` in the beginning of your code.

**2)** `"SELECT * FROM  mrsh7on  WHERE`major`='$major'"` Where are you getting the `$major` from? try `echo $major;` and see what you get.

**3)** `mysql_query($sql,$link) or die("mysql_error()");` This is not the correct way, rather:

```
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

**4)** Change this: `<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit">`

to this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

> Note: If for all that works out, Please avoid using the *deprecated*
>   mysql functions and move to either `mysqli` or `PDO`.

[PHP Manual: MySQL Improved Extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

[PHP Manual: PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)